# Sending request to Spring framework(MVC) using Get method in volley in Android

Tags: android, spring, spring-mvc, networking, android-volley

I wanted to know if it is possible to send and receive request from spring framework(**spring mvc**) **using volley** in android.
Because I believe there is something as ***spring for android*** too but is it necessary to use it or can we just make the server using spring separately and use its **URL**(http://localhost:8080/...etc.) in volley for getting the response as it does usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right after excessive hours of coding and implementing all sorts of ideas.

It turns out to be not that big of a deal.

The thing is that since my spring framework(MVC) **server is local** **host** (*unhosted basically*) hence, It can't be accessed by another device through public internet.

i.e. Say I have my Spring MVC(apache tomcat server) started in my pc,
then the app can only send and receive requests to/from server if I run it in the emulator(since it runs on same device-my pc).

***So to put it simply**- I think you probably need the **same IP address** as of your **pc**(where you are running you server) to make it work if site is not hosted. Implies, run it on an emulator since it works on the same device.*

**NOTE**

when using volley or any other method(Async Task..etc.) and running app on emulator - in your **URL** string use ***10.0.2.2*** instead of ***localhost***.

**REASON**

It's the special alias to your host loopback interface i.e. **127.0.0.1** which again is normally mapped to host name-**localhost**.

The **loopback device** is a special, virtual network interface that your computer uses to communicate with itself. It is used mainly for diagnostics and troubleshooting, and to connect to servers running on the local machine.

**Hope this helps**.

Answer (score 0):

You can build restful api using spring mvc. Check [this guide to build restful api](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Answer (score 0):

On your `app/build.gradle` put follow code:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    ...
}
```

Your call request must be similar to this:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest("http://localhost:8080/...etc",
        null, //if jsonRequest == null then Method.GET otherwise Method.POST
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        //handler the response here
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //handler the error here
    }
});
queue.add(request);
```

Comment: I have already written the perfect code for volley(Json object Request), because it works with other URLs except the one I made using spring framework(MVC). It always says connection refused as error cause, and I have got rid of any kind of firewall and proxy issues

Comment: A nice alternative is [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). My reguards bro